# Passing variables into .less with python

Tags: python, less

I'm trying to take a variable in python and pass it along into a .less css file so that it can be used as a style value. I know with lessphp you can do it and its explained here http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php

Is it possible to do with python while using the client side implementation explained http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage

Comment: Pass, sorry about that. Corrected in question.